# Can inversion integral of characteristic functions on a finte interval be bounded?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, integral-transforms, fourier-transform

For a real-valued uni-variate r.v. $X$, with pdf $f(x)$ and absolute integrable cf $\varphi(t)$, we have the following transform:$$2\pi f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itx}\varphi(t)\,dt.$$ However, I want to understand that, for any given $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ (with $a<b$), what does the transform $$\mathcal F'_{a,b}\circ\varphi(t)=g(x)=\int_{a}^{b}e^{-itx}\varphi(t)\,dt$$ represent, if that makes sense at all? The closest concept seems to be the [Finite Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_Fourier_transform), which I am not familiar with.

More importantly, I want to know if there exist some finite constant $M$, so that $$|g(x)|=\left|\int_{a}^{b}e^{-itx}\varphi(t)\,dt\right|\leq M.$$ Obviously $M=b-a$ if we allow $M$ to vary, but a better guess seems to be $M=\|f(x)\|_\infty$, since $\varphi(t)$ is bounded and continuous, am I correct?

Comment: $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-itx} \varphi(t) dt$  is the Fourier transform of $\varphi(t)$, while $g(x) = \int_{-a}^b e^{-itx} \varphi(t) dt$ is the Fourier transform of $1_{t \in [a,b]} \varphi(t)$. It is also $f(x)$ convoluted with a low-pass filter, i.e. $g(x)$ is more 'smooth' than $f(x)$. From $f(x)$ you can reconstruct $\varphi(x)$ for every $x$, from $g(x)$ you can only reconstruct $\varphi(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: And  the best possible bound for $|g(x)|$ is complicated in many cases, but $\int_a^b |\varphi(t)|dt \le \|\varphi\|_{L^1}$ always works. (of course you also have $\int_a^b |\varphi(t)|dt \le (b-a) \|\varphi\|_\infty$)

Comment: @user1952009: Thank you. Let's call this finite transform $\mathcal F_{a,b}'$ for convenience; since in general $|\mathcal F f|\leq \|f\|_1$, is it true that $|\mathcal F_{a,b}' f|\leq |\mathcal F f|\leq \|f\|_1$?

Comment: it is obvious that $|\int_a^b e^{-it x} f(t)dt| \le \int_a^b |e^{-it x} f(t)|dt \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty | f(t)|dt$, no ? and really it is not called the finite Fourier transform, but the Fourier transform of $1_{t \in |a,b]} f(t)$ ($f$ restricted to $[a,b]$)

Comment: and no, $|\int_a^b e^{-it x} f(t)dt|$ doesn't have to be $\le |\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it x} f(t)dt|$

Comment: @user1952009: thanks for the insight. Can you post these as an answer? I'll accept it :)